# Styling Related Posts Horizontally

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I would like to display related posts horizontally.

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
    global $authordata, $post;
    $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID,'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );
    $output = '<div class="rp-users">';
    foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
        $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID,array(370, 300, true));
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '"class="rp-title">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I have tried the following css, but doesn't works.

```
.rp-users {display:inline-block;}
.rp-title {font-size:19px; width: 370px;text-align:left;display:block;}
```

Comment: You opened a div outside of the loop, but close it inside the loop. That's not good...

Comment: You can use float:left propertie rp-title it should work

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the div and added "float:left" to "rp-title" and it seems that the thumbnails move, but the post titles don't display below the thumbnails like before. Only one post title stays below its thumbnail. I have three thumbnails.

Comment: by adding float:left the post titles just floats to left. So the post title  don't stay below the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
global $authordata, $post;
$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID,'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );
$output = '<div class="rp-users">';
foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
    $output .= '<div class="rp-user-entry">';
    $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID,array(370, 300, true));
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '"class="rp-title">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>';
    $output .= '</div>';
}
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```

And the css:

```
.rp-users {display:block;}
.rp-user-entry { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 33.333%; }
.rp-title {font-size:19px; width: 370px;text-align:left;display:block;}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I've copied your code and pasted in my files. But nothing changes. The thumbnails still displays vertically at the left.

Comment: Work like a charm! You are guru in deed! Thank you so much for your help. I have voted up your answer but it doesn't display. I am a new user. Btw, since I upload different sizes of images, how can i scale the thumbnail in same height and width. This code "array(370, 300, true));" I have added doesn't get the thumbnails at the same dimension. I have changed it to 370, 370 but not working.

Comment: One last thing, sir. I have copied this php code from another place. But the result is that this code displays the related posts of the author based on "newest posts", not "by category". So it doesn't display correctly by category. How can I get it done by category? Thanks!

Comment: For the image dimension, at first you should set the image size to functions.php. For example: add_image_size( 'related-post-size', 370, 370, true );
and then set the new image size to the get_the_post_thumbnail function. Sample:
$output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID, 'related-post-size');

Comment: hi, thanks. But I still get the same result. You can see that it's not same in height. Please see the pic. https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8pi61fwf08lj5a/11111il.png?dl=0

Comment: Just reupload the thumbnail image, or use regenerate thumbnails plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should look like this

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
global $authordata, $post;
$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID,'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) );
$output = '<div class="rp-users">';
foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
    $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID,array(370, 300, true));
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '"class="rp-title">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>';
}
$output .= '</div>';
return $output;
```

}